# rails/activerecord search eager loaded associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple find statement as such:

```
m = MyModel.find(1, :include => :my_children)
```

With m.mychildren being an Array; is there anyway to find a particular record from within the array without having to iterate over the entire thing. If I do mychildren.find(1), a new DB query is issues, which doesn't make sense, since they are all loaded already

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a little Rails magic going on here. Where [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003122) is being overridden by [ActiveRecord::Base#find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002263) on methods created for associations.

On the upside Enumerable#find is aliased to [Enumerable#detect](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003123). 
Unfortunately Enumerable#find/Enumerable#detect have significantly different syntax from ActiveRecord::Base#find.

So you can't just do `mychildren.find(1)`, instead you've got to do `mychildren.detect{|c| c.id == 1}` if you want to avoid hitting the database again. You may also want to consider extending Array for a more DRY way of doing this.

```
class Array 
  def id_find id
    self.detect{|element| element.id == id}
  end
end
```

Comment: interesting. I suppose thats the same as doing .collect. I was hoping that rails may be hashing the id's under the cover's for a quick lookup.

Comment: No. collect will return an array that is the result of evaluating the block for each index of the calling array. Whereas the code in my solution. Returns the one first item in the array for which the block evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your asking, but have you tried [select](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002191):

```
m.mychildren.select{ |child| child == <<some_statement>> }
```

This won't hit the database assuming you've used the `:include` option as you stated in your question.

Alternatively, if you know the number of the child you want, you should be able to just use

```
m.mychildren[1]
```

Comment: I know the id of the child, not the index in the array. I am aware of the default ruby Array functions. I was just wondering if there was some rails monkeypatch which added a bit more support for looking up children.